# Get numbers from line and separate them in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this line:

```
io=9839.1MB, bw=4012.3KB/s, iops=250, runt=2511369msec
```

and I need to extract the numbers, to get an output like this:

```
9839.1 4012.3 250 2511369
```

I tried with `sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'` but numbers are not separated from each other.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove everything but digits, dots and blanks:

```
echo 'io=9839.1MB, bw=4012.3KB/s, iops=250, runt=2511369msec' | tr -cd '0-9. '
```

Output:

```
9839.1 4012.3 250 2511369
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt with `sed` is almost right, just need a add a single whitespace character for excluding from replacement,

```
sed 's/[^0-9. ]*//g' file
9839.1 4012.3 250 2511369
```

You can also use `GNU grep` with a `-E` regular expression syntax and `-o`  for matching only words which include digits and dots.

```
grep -o -E '[0-9.]+' file
9839.1
4012.3
250
2511369
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Fish**

```js
    // a group containing a digit and the literal character "." at least once
    const regex = /([\d.]+)/g
    // your string
    const haystack = `io=9839.1MB, bw=4012.3KB/s, iops=250, runt=2511369msec`
   
    console.log(haystack.match(regex))
```

**How to fish:**
Here is the fantastic regex101 featuring a wysiwyg regexp editor including a large knowledge base.
https://regex101.com/r/a2scnd/1

Answer (score 0):

With [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ var='io=9839.1MB, bw=4012.3KB/s, iops=250, runt=2511369msec'
$ echo "${var//[![:digit:]. ]}"
9839.1 4012.3 250 2511369
```

Specifically, this uses the `${parameter//pattern/string}` with an empty *`string`* and a negated bracket expression for *`pattern`*: `[![:digit:]. ]` – everything other than digits, periods and spaces.